# How to use public/shared Google Photo album as source for HTML Slideshow Gallery?

Tags: gallery, image, google

I have a site designed by Google Sites, I need some slideshow galleries for different pages of it or even multiple of them in one page.

There is an online bookmark manager toolbox called [Reabr.com](https://www.reabr.com/) that makes a very close result to what I need, but it just lacks the gallery and customization, only carousel or simple auto-play slideshow.

Also, I tried and know that tools like Google Slides can make very same result as well, but they're not responsive and may leave scroll bars and such!

Is there any API or tool or even manually way existed to add images/photos of a shared album in Google Photos inside that Slideshow Gallery?

.

.

For better disambiguation:

A Slideshow (or image carousel) looks something like [This](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp).

A Slideshow Gallery looks something like [This](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow_gallery.asp).